# Android Horizontal scrollview with spinner like features

Tags: android, android-spinner, horizontal-scrolling, android-scrollview

I want to have a horizontal view that scrolls and has for example the names of the days of the week. The user scrolls horizontally. The day selected is the one in the middle ( like a spinner selection ). You can see the below image.

[image: View example]

Is there any widget or library that can do this? Or I will have to create it from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Pager Title strip for this functionality -

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

check this link for more information - [link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this widget](https://github.com/shamanland/xdroid/blob/master/lib-widget/src/main/java/xdroid/widget/HorizontalSpinner.java) from my library: `compile 'com.shamanland:xdroid-widget:0.2.2'`

Simply include it in your layout:

```
<xdroid.widget.HorizontalSpinner
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

And set an adapter from java-code:

```
HorizontalSpinner horizontalSpinner = findViewById(R.id.horizontal_spinner);
horizontalSpinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(...));
```

Be careful, this widget doesn't act like `ListView`. It creates **all** nested views for all items from your adapter.